# Query Not Running Correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sqlquery which I have been playing around with in my php page BUT it isn't pulling out accurate results!  I have starred at this so long now I can't see anything wrong!  I am sure there is just a " or ' or ` in the wrong place!

```
<? 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ReReferral_ID FROM ReReferral Where (`ReReferral_Date` >= '" . $_POST["report_date_from"] ."-04-01 00:00:00' AND `ReReferral_Date` <= '" . $_POST["report_date_from"] ."-06-30 00:00:00') AND ReReferral_ReReferral ='1'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Basic debugging is called for. Store the SQL into a string variable and `echo $variable;` to see its contents. Does it look like you expect it to?  What are the contents of `$_POST`? ([which is vulnerable to SQL injection, by the way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php))

Comment: Put `or die(mysql_error())` after your query. That could give you a hint. :)

Comment: Also, you are using `report_date_from` for both conditions. Do you intend for one of them to be a different value (`report_date_to` for example)?

Comment: @NoLifeKing The query completes without error, but returns different rows than expected...

Comment: What's an example value for report_date_from?

Comment: Hi, wow thanks all for the replies!  There is a report_date_to.  An example value is just the year.  2013.  The SQL injection is not an issue as it will finish up on an internal server.  I have it returning the query as a number which is fine but I do not think it is correct by the amount of records on the db

Comment: What are the expected the results? The query seems right. May be the logic isn't?

Comment: The results seem much lower than expected!  What I might have to do is export all and run some excel functions to count and see, then I will know for certain.  The this that made me think it is not right as well as the low number was also the fact in my editor it did not colour the code correctly.  I will upload images

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $rdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["report_date_from"]);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT ReReferral_ID FROM ReReferral 
          WHERE `ReReferral_Date` BETWEEN  CONCAT('$rdate','-04-01 00:00:00') 
          AND CONCAT('$rdate','-06-30 00:00:00') 
          AND ReReferral_ReReferral ='1' ");
```

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the tips, unfortunately that has returned no result.  Where the number should be it is just blank.

Comment: yeah i just did and it is empty! wait no it isnt!  it says 1999 which is the date that is passed to it.

Comment: try just echo this `$_POST["report_date_from"]`

Comment: I echo'd both and they both return 1999

Comment: why you said that its emtpy before :) , ok try the query then with $rdate

Comment: Haha, sorry, that was me mistyping the 1st echo.  I have run it again and it returns a blank.

Comment: dude , if your variable is ok , then the query should work ok .

Comment: I have tried to echo the result as @spencer7593 suggested and it returned Resource id #45.  Not sure what that means

Comment: no worries, neither does google!  I will export to excel and run count functions to see if result is true, it will take a while but will be accurate and give me the answer!  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to give a good answer to your question.

One step in debugging is verifying that the string your are constructing is the SQL statement you want to execute. As a rudimentary example:

```
$sqltext = "SELECT ReReferral_ID FROM ... ";

# for debugging echo out the SQL text to be executed:
echo $sqltext;

# also check the return from mysql_query
$result = mysql_query($sqltext) or die(mysql_error());
```

---

**NOTE** I'm twitching at the usage of the deprecated mysql_ interface. For the *love* of all that is *good* and *beautiful* in this world, don't use mysql_ for new development. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

If you have to include user provided data in the SQL text (as opposed to using bind variables), then at the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string` function to thwart SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Haha!  Sorry for making you twitch!  I don't code php and mysql and I don't intend to!  I have been dropped "in it" with this project when my developer said he doesn't have time to do it 1 day before the deadline!!  I am also twitching but for very different reasons! ;-)  I have used your tip and it has returned Resource id #45